# schedule a php page which calls a stored proc in mysql to run every x seconds

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, cron, scheduler

i have a stored procedure in mysql, accessed by a php page. this page is not visible to the visitor (as this page will not any of the links in the site). this php page will just reside in the server. i am wondering if i can have the php page automatically run/loaded/.. every say 1minute by the server, so that the page will call the stored procedure every 1 minute.

i can have a scheduler run the stored proc, but since i would be doing a lot of other things using php page on the stored proc, i would like to have the php page to be scheduled for every 1minute.

is this possible? i may be wondering too much here! i do not know much about schedulers, may be thats y.

thanks!

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: mine is hosted on a linux server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a cron job:

```
  $ crontab -e
```

To run the job every minute, inside the crontab, add the entry :

```
  * * * * * /usr/bin/php pathtoyourscript.php
```

The [Wikiedia entry on Cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) has the information about what each star means.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a command-line executable, named php. You can schedule that to process a page. E.g. `php myfile.php` will run the file myfile.php. You can use the server's scheduling tools (linux cron, windows task scheduler) to run that command for you.